# Maui - create public variable once on start and trigger update

Tags: c#, syntax, global-variables, maui

I'm new to Maui/C# and still struggle to understand the logic/syntax.

I have a Collectionview bound to an instance "DateList"

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DateList}"
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Dates">
```

with multiple labels showing those dates.
DateList is created from an model "Dates" in my VM

```
DateList = new ObservableCollection<Dates>(tlist);
```

Those dates are compared to the current date and then the backgroundcolor of each label is adjusted (green = in far future, red = soon).

They are bound in `<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>` to the label:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MailToHostDate}" BackgroundColor="{Binding MailToHostDate, Converter={StaticResource colorChangedConverter}}"
```

calling:

```
public class ColorChangedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ColorChangedConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try {

           
            DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse((string)value).AddHours(12);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
            int Diff = (parsedDate - today).Days * 24 + (parsedDate - today).Hours;

            var Color1 = GeneralHelper.GetGradients(Colors.Yellow, Colors.Green, System.Convert.ToInt32(StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_Fine - StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_GetWorried) *24);
            
            if (Diff > StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_Fine * 24)
            {
                return Color1.ToArray()[Diff];
```

This works fine so far. What I dont like is that the calculations for the list of gradient colors are done for each single label. this is totally unnecessary as the calculation could be done once and then the gradient could be used as a public variable.

1. How can I implement that the gradients are calculated once the page with the CollectionView is opened?
2. How can I trigger that they are updated/recalculated every time the page comes into view again?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new field (e.g. `public Color Bg { get; set; }` )for our bound Item `Dates.cs`  and calculate value for it by using the field `MailToHostDate`.

You only need to calculate it once when initializing the value.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public class Dates
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string MailToHostDate { get; set; }

    public Color Bg { get; set; }   


    public Item(string Name,string MailToHostDate) { 
        this.Name = Name;
        this.MailToHostDate = MailToHostDate;

        //here you can caculate the background and assign value for it.

        //DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse((string)value).AddHours(12);

         DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(MailToHostDate).AddHours(12);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
        int Diff = (parsedDate - today).Days * 24 + (parsedDate - today).Hours;

        var Color1 = GeneralHelper.GetGradients(Colors.Yellow, Colors.Green, System.Convert.ToInt32(StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_Fine - StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_GetWorried) * 24);

        if (Diff > StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_Fine * 24)
        {
            return Color1.ToArray()[Diff];

        }

        //assign value for field Bg
        //this.Bg = 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but will it update when eg StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_Fine is changed? how to Adapt the code for my other dates? in the class dates i have "Name", "Mailtohostdate" and e. g. "finaldate". as finaldate is different from Mailtohostdate, it needs to get a different color...

Comment: What's the  code of `StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_Fine`?

Comment: i used this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570072/maui-create-public-variable-once-on-start-and-trigger-update/76570330?noredirect=1#comment135018231_76570330

as example if the variable would not be alarmlevel but FilePath:

public string FilePath
{
    get { return Preferences.Get(nameof(FilePath), ""); }
    set { Preferences.Set(nameof(FilePath), value); }
}

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by above words.  The link you shared is just this thread.  Is `StandardSettings.AlarmLevel_Fine` a variable of another class ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599331/where-to-save-net-maui-user-settings  sorry, i copied the wrong link before! the StandardSettings is just a class with a wrapper for the Preferences.Get/Set as shown in an example with FilePath. What I want to achieve is: I have a collectionview with multiple rows. each rows contains a name Label and multiple date Labels. the date Labels background should change color according to the time diff to today.