# Maui What is the standard to keep application values for MAUI projects?

Tags: configuration, maui

I'm looking for the **standard way to keep values like configurations for a MAUI App**.

I'm thinking of some thing like config.xaml or application.json file
where I can host values central. E.g. the number of search results per page.
And is there a documentation about how to use in MAUI projects? (create, integrate, use)

Some how I can't find at the search engine what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to save .Net MAUI user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599331/where-to-save-net-maui-user-settings)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?tabs=android

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

1. You can save a xaml file and read and write in it. You can use FileSystemHelper for it.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers)
2. If you only want a xaml file which nobody can see, you can also use SecureStorage. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage). Important to mention is, that you should only store small amounts of data. If not it could bring performance issues.
3. The last option is to implement a SQLite Database. If you allready know that you will also store classes, it will be the best option. Here is a guide how to implement it. (https://youtube.com/watch?v=O1UQfoh4710&feature=share8)